# Handle two diffrent xml files on single request : Android

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, xml-parsing, saxparser

First off all I didn't find better title for my question, so please update if you have some words.

**What I am doing :**

*In current I am sending two request for this purpose(One for user validation, another for data, if user is authorised). But I want to use single request.*

**What I want :**

I will send a request as POST method to server where server will send a XML as response depends on my request.

For example :

- I am sending user and password to server.
- Server authenticate that user.
- If user authorised, server sends response xml as

  [image]
- If authentication failed, server sends response as

[image]

Problem I faced :

I am not able to handle XML data, actually not identify the xml data.

***I am using android.sax parser and I created two parser classes for both type of xml response, But how can I identify which parser class should I use depends on response?***

Update :

Here is my actual xml

[image][image]

So how can I parse it, using single parser?

Comment: Why dont you just use one parser? Just let the error parser return null or some kind of flag which tells you about the error.

Comment: David Olsson  I can use single parser. But I have no idea about how can I use single parser for different different XML. Please provide some info.

Comment: I've posted an answer with an example to be able to use one single parser.

Comment: See http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/xmltutorial.html for examples and documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a data structure which allows for the parser to see if it has failed or not. 
Example:

```
public class XMLResponse {
 private boolean hasFailed;
 private Employee employee;
 public void setFailure(boolean in) {
    this.hasFailed=in;
 }
 public void setEmployee(Employee in) {
    this.employee=in;
 }
}
```

And in your parser, see if the response is false or not. This is based on the fact that your response from the webservice does not contain the response tag if its successful.

Here is an example of a parser, might need some tweaks before it can be used. It is only useful if you only get 1 employee in your response, otherwise you need to use a list.

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private XMLResponse myResponse;
private Employee employee;
public XMLResponse getParsedData() { 
    return this.myResponse;
}
@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    myResponse = new XMLResponse();
    employee = new Employee();
}

@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,

        String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    buffer = new StringBuffer();
    if(localName.equals("employee")) {
        employee.setId(atts.getValue("id"));
    }
}
@Override

public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)

throws SAXException {

    if(localName.equals("response")) {
        if(buffer.toString().contains("failure")) {
            myResponse.setFailure(true);
        }
    }
    else if(localName.equals("info")) {
        /*
         * This is only an example, could bee employee or whatever. You should use the startElement to get the tag. 
         */
    }
    else if(localName.equals("name")) {
        employee.setName(buffer.toString());
    }
    else if(localName.equals("age")) {
        employee.setAge(buffer.toString());
    }
    else if(localName.equals("employee")) {
        myResponse.setEmployee(employee);
    }


}

/** Gets be called on the following structure:

 * <tag>characters</tag> */


StringBuffer buffer;
@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {

    buffer.append(ch,start,length);
}
```

Comment: This is great! But problem is same my second XML(actually) is different. I just putted an example of XML. May I put my actual XML?

Comment: Yes, put it in your question. It doesnt matter actually, you just have to change the localName.equals("yourRealTags") in the different if-cases.

Comment: Would be easier if you copied the text and not added pictures. Are you sure the columns are just named columns and not a real name? If you don't know the names you will need to try to figure out what they are depending on what the contain. Lets say that buffer.toString() only gives you number it is probably the age. But your XML seems a bit rough. I gave you an example and I dont have time to do all the code for you. Try to see if you can get more unique names of the tags.

Comment: Try reading about it at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/ under xml parser.

Comment: How to read <Tag tag_attr="10"> value of tag_attr using above method?

Comment: atts.getValue("tag_attr"); in startElement

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to have a response class specifically suited for communicating response values. A common structure is:

- IsError
- Message
- Data

The idea is that for every response, you can check to see whether it was an error ... if so, you can display the value in Message to the user. IF not, take the 'data', and deserialize it